# Windows 7 hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, hibernate

I would a script that can be entered as a Start > Run command to put the computer into hibernate mode.

I have done this in Windows Vista; I just need the Windows 7 command to start the hibernate command.

Answer (score 3):

<s>`Shutdown /h /t 1 /c "I'm packing it in for the winter!"`</s>

Don't have too much fun now
**edit**

Humm, looks like Hibernate doesn't record a comment.

So it is just `Shutdown /h`

Comment: +1 for the "I'm packing it in for the winter!" FINALLY someone on this site with a sense of humor. I am surprised they have not edited your answer! :)

Comment: It will always be like that. It's easy to be cold hearted. But when you  realize that, in the end it's all dust and ashes, you start caring less about what people say and do.

Comment: tried      Shutdown /h /t 1 /c

Comment: command prompt ran, no turn off

Comment: Ya, I edited it.  You can't put fun comments with your /h

Comment: Yes! it works!     Where would u find what code commanded what? Like the hibernate command you found. Where do you find that?

Comment: I took a guess.  I figured that if the shutdown tool can restart, shutdown and logoff a machine, chances are it will have hibernation.  Otherwise, I would of googled Microsoft's Technet library.